# Kendo UI grid filter with refresh button

Tags: filter, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI grid and a refresh button. I would like to prevent grid rebinding on filter change. I would like to collect filters into a collection instead. If the user clicks on the refresh button, the grid should be rebinded and the filters should be applied. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible out of the box. Clicking the "Filter" button of the grid filter menu would cause immediate filtering.

Comment: This is possible for example in Telerik Web Forms Grid. I was hoping I can achieve this somehow in Kendo UI. Can you prove your proposition somehow?

Comment: Well I implemented the Kendo UI Grid filtering. Can't think of a better proof.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know. Is there a planned future release which enable me to solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Tank you for the quick answer and the tip.